# Does knowing $g, g^r, g^{r^2}, g^{r^3}, \dotsc$ sometimes offer a significant advantage in finding $r$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

Is there a cyclic group $\mathcal G$ with generator $g$ for which the discrete log problem is assumed to be hard, but knowing $g, g^r, g^{r^2}, g^{r^3}, \dotsc$ for random $r$ makes finding $r$ easy?

I don't expect to get an answer but I'll award a bounty if I get a good one.

[edit]

This might be related: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-288/S0025-5718-2014-02813-5/S0025-5718-2014-02813-5.pdf
The best it seems to offer is $O(p^{1/2})$ which is $n/2$ bit of improvement over brute force if I've read it correctly.